# Running cron.daily in parallel

Tags: bash, cron

Being able to put a script in /etc/cron.daily is really nice because I can do it easily from a configuration management system or a package.  However, my understanding is that all the entries in /etc/cron.daily will run sequentially.  How can I make a script in /etc/cron.daily not hold up the other tasks?  Would something like the following work?

```
#!/bin/bash
#do something long:
nohup sleep 1000000000 &;#instead of sleep, this could point to another script that takes a while to execute
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you background the process in the script, the next one will be started. Scripts in `/etc/cron.daily` are run by `run-parts` (from `man cron`):

> Support for /etc/cron.hourly, /etc/cron.daily, /etc/cron.weekly and /etc/cron.monthly is provided  in  Debian  through
>      the  default  setting  of  the  /etc/crontab file (see the system-wide example in crontab(5)).  The default sytem-wide
>      crontab contains four tasks: run every hour, every day, every week and every month. Each of these tasks  will  execute
>      run-parts  providing  each  one  of  the  directories as an argument. These tasks are disabled if anacron is installed
>      (except for the hourly task) to prevent conflicts between both daemons.

So, you can simulate by running it manually. For example:

```
$ ls /etc/cron.daily/
test1  test2
$ cat test1
#!/bin/bash
echo starting 1  >> /tmp/haha
sleep 1000000000 & 
$ cat test2
#!/bin/bash
echo starting 2  >> /tmp/haha
sleep 1000000000 &

$ sudo run-parts /etc/cron.daily
$ cat /tmp/haha
starting 1
starting 2
```

In the example above, I created two scripts that simply run `sleep 1000000000 &`. Because of the `&`, the process is sent to the background and `run-parts` moves on to the next script. So, `nohup` is not needed, all you need is the `&` at the end of the line that will take a while.

Comment: Do both scripts have the "&"?  In your sample code, only one script does.

Comment: @Daniel yes, thanks, that was a typo. Strictly speaking, the last script to be run (alphabetical) does not need it since nothing will be run after it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It's just a script so you can do anything you want.